# Best practice to update the Application Insights instrumentation key for classic Desktop apps

Tags: c#, wpf, azure-application-insights

**The problem...**

We have a "classic" windows desktop application (WPF) which sends telemetry data via Application Insights. The instrumentation key is currently deployed with the application. For sake of simplicity let's assume it's hard coded ;-)

Recently we've discovered, if once we delete a Application Insights resource in azure it cannot be recovered. Therefor the instrumentation key is lost. However we can make of course a new instance. But the instrumentation key is different. How to change the instrumentation key on all of our existing installations (on premises)?

**Solution so far**

Instead of "hardcode" the instrumentation key, we get it from "the cloud" via [azure functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/). We make a REST call to get the instrumentation key. Obviously now the URL to this function is hardcoded instead of the key itself. If the instrumentation key ever changes, we can update it in this function, without creating a new release of our software and update all our clients.

**This works. But...**

... is there any (simpler) other way to deal with that? Maybe there is already a built in method, API, etc. that does this?

any ideas are appreciated

Mat

Comment: have you tried contacting support? you may or may not be able to recover a deleted AI resource, depending on how long it has been, or you may or may not be able to swap out an old ikey onto a new app.  I'd check with support first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution of getting the key from a remote service or API via REST is viable. The client application could also connect to some kind of telemetry service which in turn communicates with Azure and stores the key. Then the client only needs to know the address to the REST service and possible also how to authorize itself.

Another solution would be to specify the key in an application configuration file and tell the end users to update the configuration file themselves, or provide an updated configuaration file whenever the instrumentation key is changed. This at least saves you from having to rebuild and redeploy the binaries. Obviously, you will need to do this if you hardcode the key into the code.

Comment: Thx for your respone. Actually it's already a configuration parameter ;-) I just simplified things for my question. Anyway it's not possible to reach out to all customers to update the instrumentation key manually. Or do you ever got an Email from google to update some config file in chrome in order they can gather more data from you? This would be some kinda awkward...

Comment: On the other hand it would be just as weird if they included an expirable key required to be able use the browser in the code. That's why I suggested storing the actual key required to connect to Azure remotely.